# Creating an Employee Punch Clock

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a way to clock in and clock out at work using python and tkinter. There are several features to be implemented.

- Change the Employee Name
- Clock In button
- Clock Out button
- Export file with the information

I have all the components and they work when I run the different features individually. When I try to combine to one script, the program fails.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
       Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
    self._start = 0.0        
    self._elapsedtime = 0.0
    self._running = 0
    self.timestr = StringVar()               
    self.makeWidgets()  

    def makeWidgets(self):                         
        """ Make the time label. """
        l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)                      

    def _update(self): 
        """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)                
        self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

    def Start(self):                                                     
        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
            self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
            self._update()
            self._running = 1        

    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

    def Reset(self):                                  
        """ Reset the stopwatch. """
        self._start = time.time()         
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0    
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

    def clock_in(self):
        global e1              
        data = e1.get()
        ClockIn_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        ClockIn_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        totalinput = [ data, ClockIn_time, ClockIn_date] 
        with open(r"C:\Users\Desktop\ClockIn.csv", "a") as savedb:
            w = csv.writer(savedb)
            w.writerow(totalinput)

    def clock_out(self):
        global e1              
        data = e1.get()
        ClockOut_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        ClockOut_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        totalinput = [ data, ClockOut_time , ClockOut_date ] 
        with open(r"C:\Users\Desktop\ClockIn.csv", "a") as savedb:
            w = csv.writer(savedb)
            w.writerow(totalinput)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    sw = StopWatch(root)
    sw.pack(side=TOP)
    root.geometry("400x400")

    ####
    label = tk.Label(root, text="Employee Name: ")
    label.pack(side="top")

    new = StringVar()
    e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=new)
    e1.pack()
    #######

    Button(root, text='Clock In', command=lambda :[sw.Start(), sw.clock_in()]).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Clock Out', command=lambda :[sw.Start(), sw.clock_out()]).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm having trouble `get()` the employees name and saving to a file. I've created a stand alone tkinter app, I'm able to do this, when I implement multiple features I cannot get them all to marinate.

Comment: *When I try to combine to one script, the program fails.* - it's a question about different program **state**, but not about the quality of a working program

Comment: Depends on the definition of fails. The program runs. It fails the requirements. So it's a poor quality working code.

Comment: @JohnFriel Code that doesn't meet the requirements is broken/not working code here (and probably everywhere) :) When your code will work, don't hesitate to post it here and we will help you make it better. Until then, I'm afraid your question is off-topic. Also, I edited your indentation, I think it looked this way because of when you pasted it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Incorrect indention

All of the methods in a class need to be indented such that they are inside the class definition. (this is based on the original version of the code you posted.

Instead of this:

```
 class StopWatch(Frame):  
   """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
   def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw): ...

def makeWidgets(self): ...                        
def _update(self): ...
def _setTime(self, elap): ...
def Start(self): ...                                                  
def Stop(self): ...                                  
def Reset(self): ...                                 
def clock_in(self): ...
def clock_out(self): ...
```

You need to do this:

```
class StopWatch(Frame):  
   """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw): ...

    def makeWidgets(self): ...                        
    def _update(self): ...
    def _setTime(self, elap): ...
    def Start(self): ...                                                  
    def Stop(self): ...                                  
    def Reset(self): ...                                 
    def clock_in(self): ...
    def clock_out(self): ...
```

### Follow PEP8 Guidelines

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) gives guidelines that every python program should follow. Specifically in your case, function names need to begin with a lowercase character.

### StringVar is unnecessary overhead

In most cases, using `StringVar` adds overhead with no real value. While this is more of a personal preference, I see no reason to use it. `StringVar` objects are good if you want the exact same value displayed in two or more widgets, or if you're wanting to trace changes. Otherwise they are superfluous.

Instead of `self.timestr`, you can directly alter the widget value. So, instead of saving a reference to the `StringVar`, save a reference to the widget:

```
def makeWidgets(self): 
    ...                        
    self.time_label = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
    ...  

def _setTime(self, elap):
    ...           
    self.time_label.configure(text='%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))
    ...
```

### Be consistent with private methods

By convention, private methods (methods that are only used internally) are named with a leading underscore. You do this with `_update` and `_setTime`, but you didn't do it with `makeWidgets`. You should try to be consistent: if a function is only used internally, name it with a leading underscore.

### Don't hard-code the filename

Your program would be a bit more portable if you didn't hard-code the filename. Right now you have the filename hard-coded in the `clock_in` and `clock_out` functions.

Instead, make it a parameter when you instantiate the class, or make it global.

For example:

```
def clock_in(self):
    ...
    with open(self.filename, "a") as savedb:
    ...

def clock_out(self):
    ...
    with open(self.filename, "a") as savedb:
    ...
sw = StopWatch(root, filename=r"C:\Users\Desktop\ClockIn.csv")
```

### Separate widget creation from widget layout

In my experience, separating widget creation makes the code easier to visualize and easier to maintain.

Instead of this:

```
Button(root, text='Clock In', command=lambda :[sw.Start(), sw.clock_in()]).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(root, text='Clock Out', command=lambda :[sw.Start(), sw.clock_out()]).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(root, text='Reset', command=sw.Reset).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=LEFT)
```

... do this:

```
clock_in_button = Button(...)
clock_out_button = Button(...)
reset_button = Button(...)
quit_button = Button(...)

clock_in_button.pack(side=LEFT)
clock_out_button.pack(side=LEFT)
reset_button.pack(side=LEFT)
quit_button.pack(side=LEFT)
```

This makes it much more clear to see at a glance that all for buttons are aligned to the left. When it's all blocked together it's much harder to see.

### Incorrect use of tkinter

You're importing tkinter with `import tkinter as tk` but then trying to use tk classes without the `tk.` prefix.

The import is good, but you need to fix all of the code that is creating widgets. For example, `tk.Button(...)` instead of just `Button(...).

Comment: Great places to start. Thank you for the bullet points.